# Resize Chart Right to Left

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I need help please in resizing Excel charts to expan right versus the standard expanding left.

I input the vba code below to each chart to resize and it works fine, except for the charts of the right side of the workbook, it expands off the screen and I don't want to have to scroll right.

How can I modify the code so that it expands left versus rt?

Thanks!

```
Sub Chart140_Click()
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(Application.Caller)
    If .Height = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("configuration").Range("chrtrngzoominh")) Then
        .Height = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("configuration").Range("chrtrngzoomouth"))
        .Width = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("configuration").Range("chrtrngzoomoutw"))
    Else
        .Height = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("configuration").Range("chrtrngzoominh"))
        .Width = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("configuration").Range("chrtrngzoominw"))
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: When you enter code, paste it, then select it, then use the code brackets symbol to format it. Or click the code format symbol and then paste the code over the text "enter code here"

Answer (score 0):

Excel charts are positioned with the top left corner. If you want to change the size of a chart and and anchor the **right** hand side, you will need to use a workaround along these lines:

- save the initial chart position of the top left into variables
- save the initial chart width into a variable
- increase the chart width
- calculate the width difference between initial and the new width
- adjust the top left position by the width difference